# Solution to initial value problem with equation in x,y

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve the initial value problem: $yy'+x=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, with $y(4)=-\sqrt{48}$.
The problem specifically asks for a solution to the initial value problem described by an equation in $x,y$.

When I worked through this problem, the answer I got was:
$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=7$, which was wrong.
My steps: u substition with $u=x^2+y^2$; $u'=2x+2yy'$; gives linear equation $\frac{u'-2x}{2}+x=\sqrt{u}$

Comment: Please add some steps of your solution, it is not obvious how you got there. I see $\sqrt{x^2+y(x)^2}=4+x$.

Comment: So far so good. Now you can separate to $\frac{u'}{2\sqrt u}=1$ and integrate. I still can not see how that results in the right side being $7$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

$$
\frac 12(y^2+x^2)' = \sqrt{y^2+x^2}
$$

or

$$
\frac 12u' = \sqrt{u}\Rightarrow u =  x^2+c_0 x+ \frac{c_0}{4}
$$